# Migration guide for Spring security 5

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-security

I have multi-module maven project Spring boot 2.3.1.RELEASE, there I use spring security over OAuth 2.0. One of my modules contains configuration for security:

Authorization server config

```java
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer //deprecated
public class AuthorizationServerOAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter { //deprecated

    private static final String SINGING_KEY = "";
    private static final String CLIENT_ID = "";
    private static final String CLIENT_SECRET = "";
    private static final String[] AUTHORIZED_GRANT_TYPES = {"password", "refresh_token"};
    private static final String[] SCOPES = {"read", "write"};

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) { //deprecated
        security
                .tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception { //deprecated

        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient(CLIENT_ID)
                .secret(passwordEncoder.encode(CLIENT_SECRET))
                .authorizedGrantTypes(AUTHORIZED_GRANT_TYPES)
                .scopes(SCOPES)
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(1800)
                .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(9600);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) { //deprecated

        endpoints
                .tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() { //deprecated
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setSigningKey(SINGING_KEY);
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() { //deprecated
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() { //deprecated
        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }
}
```

Resource server config

```java
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer //deprecated
public class ResourceServerOAuth2Config extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter { //deprecated
}
```

pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.skill.improvement</groupId>
        <artifactId>app</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>security</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <!-- 2.3.1.RELEASE -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <!-- 2.3.1.RELEASE -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Main security config

```java
@Order(1)
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String ADMIN_PASSWORD = "";
    private static final String USER_PASSWORD = "";

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .csrf().disable()
                .anonymous().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/v1/**").authenticated()
                .and().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint())
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler()) //deprecated
                .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring()
                .antMatchers(
                "/v2/api-docs",
                "/configuration/ui",
                "/swagger-resources/**",
                "/configuration/security",
                "/swagger-ui.html",
                "/webjars/**")
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/v1/**")
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PATCH, "/v1/**");
    }

    @Autowired
    public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(inMemoryUserDetailsManager());
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager inMemoryUserDetailsManager() {

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(getDefaultUsers());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public OncePerRequestFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
    }

    private List<UserDetails> getDefaultUsers() {

        List<UserDetails> userDetailsList = new ArrayList<>();
        userDetailsList.add(User.withUsername("admin").password(passwordEncoder().encode(ADMIN_PASSWORD))
                .roles("ADMIN").build());
        userDetailsList.add(User.withUsername("user").password(passwordEncoder().encode(USER_PASSWORD))
                .roles("USER").build());
        return userDetailsList;
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, but almost everything is deprecated since Spring Security 5.2.x. I read [this guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Migration-Guide)

but I am not sure how to successfully finish the migration. Is there any understandable guide on how to do it?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to migrate TokenStore, TokenServices etc to the new Spring Security version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone, who wants to use the newest solution the Spring already released [the authorization server](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started.html).

Maven dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Before rushing to it, one should be aware that it is still far behind other "well known" OIDC authorization-servers in terms of features: multi factor authentication, user registration forms, clients and user management screens (including roles), social login,  connection to LDAP, etc. I really don't get the point to re-implement all that when I can just start a Keycloak instance or subscribe to an Auth0 free account...

Comment: Yes, I agree with using Keycloak potentially.

Answer (score 6):

In spring security's current release they have not given support of authorization server. They are working on authorization server support but the project is under experimental mode. Besides spring security team already integrated resource server as well as Oauth2 client support in spring security 5 as single spring security project. Until, they don't release the support of latest spring's authorization server you can use your old authorization server but you won't be able to keep your resource server auth server because latest resource server and client configuration comes in different dependency and the configurations will conflict with old oauth2 support .

I would recommend you to use any other authorization server meanwhile they release spring's latest auth server. I would suggest you to use keyclock auth server that I am personally using.

See [this](https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-authorization-server)

Comment: Thank you very much, sir. I appreciate your time to write here down the facts. I read about this current state in the spring documentation, but I forgot to close this issue with some explanation. :)

Comment: Being the spring-authorization-server still experimental and currently on version 0.1.0, I would keep using the previous "Deprecated" version till it becomes more stable rather than switching to KeyClock now to switch back later in future.

Comment: Hi, do you know a best tutorial to migrate the same situation at this date? do you know if the authorization server is available in the spring security now?

Comment: You mean migration from old spring security oauth2 to latest one ?